# How to send authorization to web app using Rest API

Tags: apex, rest-api, apexrest, authentication

This is my first time working with API and I'm trying to understand how to send authentication to an web app using REST API.

Questions I have:

1. Do I need to setup Oauth in Salesforce in order to send the username and password of to the web app so every time Salesforce makes a call, it authenticate?
2. Since Web App requires a authenticated user who has API access, what is the best approach here? Do I create a dummy user in the Web API and pass the username and password in my code (I'm assuming it's called the Header) to authenticate?

Below are one document and a posts I found to be helpful but I'm still a bit confused as it doesn't go in depth to describe each element.

User post I found to show how it works: 
[How to set the Authorization Header](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/53428/how-to-set-the-authorization-header)

Salesforce doc on Oath and Rest API
[Setup Authorization](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/quickstart_oauth.htm)

grant_type <---- what is a grant type and how do I find this information? 
client_id is the Consumer Key <---- What is a consumer key? 
client_secret is the Consumer Secret <----- I'm assuming this is the certification? 
redirect_uri is the Callback URL <--- this is the URL I will be pinging?

I would appreciate if you can explain some of these questions I have or share any links?

Thank you.

Comment: [Understanding Authentication](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_authentication.htm) is a good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need to setup Oauth in Salesforce in order to send the username and password of to the web app so every time Salesforce makes a call, it authenticate?

OAuth authentication is a native part of Salesforce. Your remote application must complete an OAuth authentication flow to gain access to Salesforce, unless you perform a SOAP API login via username and password to get a session Id (*strongly* discouraged).

Completing authentication will provide you with an access token you can use to obtain access to Salesforce APIs. Depending on which OAuth flow you implement, you may also receive a refresh token that will allow your application to get new sessions when this expires, without redoing the original OAuth flow.

> Do I create a dummy user in the Web API and pass the username and password in my code (I'm assuming it's called the Header) to authenticate?

Using an integration user (a user that is purposed, and permissioned, exclusively for some external application to connect under) is very common. No, you absolutely should not pass credentials around in plaintext. Your remote application should complete an OAuth flow.

The `Authorization: Bearer <token>` header is how you provide your access token to Salesforce. It does not include a username or password.

> grant_type <---- what is a grant type and how do I find this information? client_id is the Consumer Key <---- What is a consumer key? client_secret is the Consumer Secret <----- I'm assuming this is the certification? redirect_uri is the Callback URL <--- this is the URL I will be pinging?

OAuth is complex. Secure authentication, in general, is complex, and mistakes have critical consequences for your users and systems. I'd strongly recommend you read through [Understanding Authentication](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_authentication.htm) and [Authenticate Apps with OAuth](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_authenticate.htm&type=5) in detail, as well as making yourself familiar with the available libraries and best practices for the stack in which you're building this remote application. Most likely, your application should be using the Web Server, User Agent, or JWT flows. You should avoid using the Username-Password flow.

The Client Id and Consumer Secret are key identifiers of your Connected App, which define *who* the remote authorizing application is. The Callback URL is the URL in *your* app that *Salesforce* will call with a token when authorization is completed successfully. The documentation for the OAuth flow you're implementing will inform you as to the expected values for `grant_type`.